# How do I set timeouts per request using Spring REST Template?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an application that makes use of multiple rest clients. Each of those REST clients use the same Spring REST template bean. I was wondering if there was a way to set the timeout value per request using the Spring rest template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());

private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    int timeout = 5000;
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory
      = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    return clientHttpRequestFactory;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! However, is there a way to do it without creating a new httpclient instance each time? We are reusing the Spring rest template bean across those rest clients. If we define the timeout in the factory above, then that would define it globally for all clients instead of a different one for each client. I am wondering if I just have to create an instance of rest template for each client.

Comment: @JCB: Why have you accepted this answer? It does not set the timeout per request using the same instance of Spring `RestTemplate` like you asked. Have you found somewhere else that *this* is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve calling rest template with timeout, first you should create config class also use with @Bean annotation, then implement in class and call with RestTemplateConfig.

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
    }

    private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(4000);
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(4000);
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(4000);
        return clientHttpRequestFactory;
    }
}
```

But I suggest you use Apache HttpClient, you can manage the connection pool, keep-alive, idle monitor and also create custom error handler. You can check the link: https://springframework.guru/using-resttemplate-with-apaches-httpclient/

Answer (score -1):

You can also modify the SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(customHttpRequestFactory());

private SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory customHttpRequestFactory() {
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(2000);
    simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    return simpleClientHttpRequestFactory;
}
```

Comment: None of the answers here describes how  time out is set per rest call